# Mutation target specification

Tags: java, mutation

I am trying to create mutants using the Java mutation testing tool called "[Major](http://mutation-testing.org/)".

I want to specify the function I want the mutants for. The problem is that the class has multiple functions with the same name and different arguments. Is there any way to choose only the function that I want?

Comment: You say "the major tool", but it's not clear which tool you're talking about. Could you explain exactly what you're running and how? (include command line options or GUI tick boxes etc)

Comment: The tool i am using is this http://mutation-testing.org/. I am using the major compiler and apache ant in order to get the mutants.

Comment: That's an unfortunate name. I've edited the question to be clear about the tool. Could you show the specific Ant configuration you're using to choose which methods to mutate?

Comment: At the moment i am using this command: target2="xorg.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils@lastIndexOf"; There are multiple lastIndexOf function in ArrayUtils, so i am getting mutants for all of them.